# How do I customize the ordering of vectors in R

Tags: r

I'm a newbie, and now I have a problem: I have vector A, which is arranged in order of "T1、T2、T3、T5、T7、T8、T4、T6、T9", but now I want it to be arranged in order of "T1-T9" and correspond to the correct values. What do I need to do?

```
A<-c(0.301,0.218,0.153,0.116,0.085,0.056,0.033,0.024,0.013)
names(A)<-c("T1","T2","T3","T5","T7","T8","T4","T6","T9")
A
```

Comment: What are the correct values? What is the expected result?

Comment: Use `levels` from `forcats`

Comment: Can you give me the detailed code and the result？ Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the example shared using `order`/`sort` would work directly :

```
A[order(names(A))]

#   T1    T2    T3    T4    T5    T6    T7    T8    T9 
#0.301 0.218 0.153 0.033 0.116 0.024 0.085 0.056 0.013
```

---

But if `"T"` values go beyond 9 this will not work. For example,

```
A<-c(0.301,0.218,0.153,0.116,0.085,0.056,0.033,0.024,0.013, 0.1)
names(A)<-c("T1","T2","T3","T5","T7","T8","T4","T10","T9", "T6")
A[order(names(A))]

#   T1   T10    T2    T3    T4    T5    T6    T7    T8    T9 
#0.301 0.024 0.218 0.153 0.033 0.116 0.100 0.085 0.056 0.013
```

This is because `order`/`sort` would lexicographically sort the names.

In which case you can use `gtools::mixedorder`/`gtools::mixedsort`

```
A[gtools::mixedorder(names(A))]
#   T1    T2    T3    T4    T5    T6    T7    T8    T9   T10 
#0.301 0.218 0.153 0.033 0.116 0.100 0.085 0.056 0.013 0.024
```

In base R, you can remove all non-numerics, convert to integer and order

```
A[order(as.numeric(gsub('\\D', '', names(A))))]
#Or
#A[order(as.numeric(sub('T', '', names(A))))]
```

---

**EDIT**

Based on comments from OP if you want data in custom order you can use `match` + `order` :

```
x <- c("PED", "CADP", "GWP", "EP", "POCP", "HI", "AP", "ODP", "RI")
correct_order <- c("PED", "CADP", "GWP", "AP", "EP", "ODP", "POCP", "HI", "RI")

x[order(match(x, correct_order))]

#[1] "PED"  "CADP" "GWP"  "AP"   "EP"   "ODP"  "POCP" "HI"   "RI"
```

Comment: thank you，this answer can indeed solve the problem，but if the vector A name is c(“PED”, “CADP”, “GWP”, “EP”, “POCP”, “HI ”, “AP”, “ODP”, "RI"), I want to the value of A to follow in this order c（“PED”, “CADP”, “GWP”, “AP”, “EP”, “ODP”, “POCP”, “HI ”, "RI"），what can I do？

Comment: there is no logic，just I want to do it in this order，Is there a program that can implement this custom order？

Comment: @WHB533 Yes, check the last part in updated answer. You can use `match` with `order`.